# iOS restore causes downloading issues

Tags: ipad, ios, restore

I restored my iPad today. The first, say, 30 apps redownloaded fine after the restore, but now my screens are filled with "Waiting..." icons. I've tried downloading something else and entering my Apple ID password, I've tried restarting, but nothing seems to get the other apps to download. What can I do?

Comment: Be patient. Sometimes a restart works, sometimes resetting your network connection works. It can take time.

Comment: I've tried restarting, and absolutely nothing has happened for the past 19 hours or so, but I'll try resetting the network connection. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: That didn't seem to work...I'm going to try reinitiating the restore. I haven't really done anything on it since then, so data loss won't be an issue.

Comment: Re-restoring it seems to be doing the trick. I'll submit that as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugging it in to iTunes again and re-restoring it did the trick.

Comment: Glad you resolved the problem!